# Should kitten be isolated to one room?

Tags: cats, toilet-training, multi-pet-families

My kitten is still in the process of potty training. I have only had him for a week so he is still learning the layout of the house. He has only had one accident during this time. Should I lock him up in the room with his litter box while I am at work? If so, for how long should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a big house, yes. Being young, it might just have a hard time remembering where the litter box is. Or it's less aware of when it's going to need to use it, so it hits all at once and the litterbox isn't near by.  Just like a child.